# The view from PostGIS isn't rendered in ArcGIS Pro 3

Tags: postgis, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3 with an Enterprise DB based on PostgreSQL/PostGIS. After the upload on the DB of a polygon layer, I've created a view using DBeaver for dissolve some polygons.

```
CREATE VIEW asl_campania AS
SELECT
    scc.cod_asl,
    scc.asl,
    ST_UNION(scc.shape)
FROM soresa_comuni_campania scc 
GROUP BY scc.cod_asl, scc.asl
```

I can see that view in the catalog but when I add it on my ArcGIS project the view isn't rendered on map but added to the TOC. Why happen this?

This procedure is very easy to do using a standard PostGIS DB and QGIS, I've done it a lot of times. I'm new with Esri products.

Comment: Can you update your post with some images or code?

Comment: Done it @MarcoReliquias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esri products work fine with views, but to work, need a geometry name and to speed up geometries load, need an ID column. Try out the code below:

```
CREATE VIEW asl_campania as
    SELECT
    row_number() over(order by scc.cod_asl) OBJECTID,
    scc.cod_asl,
    scc.asl,
    ST_UNION(scc.shape) SHAPE
FROM soresa_comuni_campania scc 
GROUP BY scc.cod_asl, scc.asl
```

Comment: It's far better to have a natural compound identifier (cod_asl, asl) in a Query Layer than one where the ID value changes depending on which features are selected (which violates the whole point of a rowid column). Note that the ID does *not* "speed up" geometry load, and ST_Union queries will be very slow, every time (for which a MATERIALIZED VIEW may be a solution, depending on the update frequency of the source table).